# Send data to WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, wkwebview

I am creating a View which displays a local webpage which also has styles and JavaScript (Essentially a hybrid native application) and I am using a WKWebView.

I know how to send data from the JavaScript to the native code but it is not clear how to do it the reverse way. I am wanting to send a JSON Object that is fetched using native iOS code to my MKWebView.

I am getting the following error

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo=0x7bfb3c30 {NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
    nil
```

Below is my code.

```
//
//  WebViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Adam Bulmer on 09/03/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Adam Bulmer. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import WebKit

class WebViewController: BaseViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {

        super.loadView()

        var config = WKWebViewConfiguration();
        var contentController = WKUserContentController();

        var userScript = WKUserScript(
            source: "bootstrap()",
            injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd,
            forMainFrameOnly: true
        )

        contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        config.userContentController = contentController;


        self.webView = WKWebView(frame:self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;

        self.view = self.webView!

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(webViewName(),
            ofType: "html");

        var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!);
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);

        self.webView!.loadRequest(request);

    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        var param = "Hello World";
        var exec_template = "test(\(param)');";

        self.webView!.evaluateJavaScript(exec_template, completionHandler: { (test, error) -> Void in
            println(error);
            println(test);
        })

    }

    func webViewName() -> String {
        return "";
    }

// MARK: WKScriptMessageHandler callback
// Delegate callback for when scripts sends message

    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
    var param = "Hello World";
    var exec_template = "test(\(param)');";
```

Will result in ..

```
test(Hello World');
```

.. being executed, which is not valid JS. You missed the opening `'` in your code.